# Right clicking showing contextual menu fullcalendar plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I wanted to create a simple copy and paste right click menu functionaliuty in fullcalendar. So I used the eventRender callback to open a contextual menu like this:

```
eventRender: function (event, element){
            element.bind('contextmenu', function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                console.log('Right clicking');
                showContextualMenu(event, element, e);
            });
        }


 function showContextualMenu(event,element, e){
     console.log(event);
     if (event.canceled){

         $("#contextual-menu li#cancel").html("Undo Cancel");
     }else{
         $("#contextual-menu li#cancel").html("Cancel Appointment");
     }
         $("#contextual-menu").css({
             'position':'fixed',
             'top':e.clientY,
             'left':e.clientX
         }).fadeIn(500, function (){
             $(document).bind("click", function(){
                 $('#contextual-menu').hide(500);                     
                 $(document).off("click");
             });
             var options = $("#contextual-menu ul").children();
             options.one('click', function (){
                 console.log("Inside click");
                 if ($(this).data('action' )=== "move"){
                     console.log("Inside if")
                     alert("Copied event to move it");
                     copiedEvent = event;
                     paste = true;
                 }else {
                     if (!event.canceled) {
                         console.log("Not canceled");
                         console.log("Cancel");
                         var reason_id = $("#reason").prop('id');
                         $("#modal-cancel").attr('data-id', event.id);
                         $("#modal-cancel").modal('show')
                     }else {
                         uncancelEvent(event);
                     }

                 }
             });
         });
     }
```

I also select all day slots and bind them two the context menu to show the paste menu

```
var slots;
slots = $(".fc-slats > table tbody tr ").find("td:eq(1)");
console.log(slots.length);
slots.bind('contextmenu', function (e){
console.log("binding slots");
console.log(paste);
e.preventDefault();
if (paste===true) {
    showSlotContextualMenu($(this), e);
}
```

It works great until I choose to move to another day. Then the binding is lost and clicking on a day slot won't  show contextual menu. Why is that?

Comment: have you found any solution yet to this ?